# Activate Workbook With Month and Year in Name

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA macro and I need to activate a workbook called Monthly Management Report June 2017 (the month will always be the previous month). 
I am using the following code

```
Windows("Monthly Life Management Report " & Format(Date, "mmm yyyy") & ".xlsm").Activate
```

But I am getting a Subscript out of range error.

Comment: Is this workbook open when running this code ? Also, shouldn't previous month be June, not May ?

Comment: Yes the workbook is open, apologies yes June (I am using an older file for testing) I will rename now

Comment: Replace `Windows` with `Workbooks`

Comment: Same error @Tom

Comment: Test the name and make sure the names match.  Add `msgbox "Monthly Life Management Report " & Format(Date, "mmm yyyy") & ".xlsm"` before the line and verify that everything matches the name of the workbook, including the suffix.

Comment: Select the workbook that you want to activate (i.e. June 2017) and in the immediate window type `?ActiveWorkbook.Name` Then enter `?"Monthly Life Management Report " & Format(Date, "mmm yyyy") & ".xlsm"` and make sure the two match

Comment: On the title bar of the relevant Window - does it say _Monthly Life Management Report Jul 2017.xlsm_ or _Monthly Life Management Report Jul 2017_?  This part is the `Windows Caption` and for the `Windows(...)` to work it must be as it is in the caption - duplicate your screen and it would be  _Monthly Life Management Report Jul 2017.xlsm:1_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks("Monthly Life Management Report " & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmm yyyy") & ".xlsm")
wb.Activate
```

**Note**: the name of the workbook should be saved as `"Jun 2017"` and not `"June 2017"`.

If you have a full Month as the file name, then use the line below instead:

```
Set wb = Workbooks("Monthly Life Management Report " & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy") & ".xlsm")
```

Comment: Why set it to a variable?

Comment: @E_McAndrew what is the exact name of your `Workbook` ?

Comment: Think you need `Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks all that did it

Comment: @ShaiRado and Tom I have a follow up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330266/referencing-a-workbook-variable-in-if-formula which I think ye may know the answer to. Thanks for all ye're help.