# Referencing a Workbook variable in IF formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which is comparing numbers between two workbooks and outputting if it's correct or incorrect.
One of the workbooks is stored as a variable as it references last month in it's name.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Monthly Life Management Report " & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy") & ".xlsm")
```

I am getting a application or object defined error when running the final part of the macro.

```
 Range("E8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF([wb]'2 Claims'!R8C5 =[Template.xlsx]Claims!R8C5,""Correct"",""Incorrect"")"
```

Entire Script

```
Sub Monthly_Life_Management()


Dim thisWb As Workbook
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\Validation_File_" & Format(Date, "dd mm yy") & ".xls"


Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Monthly Life Management Report " & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy") & ".xlsm")



'Claims Tab
 wb.Activate
 Sheets("2 Claims").Select

 Range("C2:C13").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Windows("Validation_File_" & Format(Date, "dd mm yy") & ".xls").Activate
 Range("C2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 wb.Activate
 Sheets("2 Claims").Select
 Range("D2:D13").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Windows("Validation_File_" & Format(Date, "dd mm yy") & ".xls").Activate
 Range("D2").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 wb.Activate
 Sheets("2 Claims").Select
 Range("E7:G7").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 Windows("Validation_File_" & Format(Date, "dd mm yy") & ".xls").Activate
 Range("E7").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

'Counts
 Range("E8").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF('[wb]2 Claims'!R8C5 ='[Template.xlsx]Claims'!R8C5,""Correct"",""Incorrect"")"

 Cells.Select
 Selection.Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak where the `'` are in the workbook reference:

```
"=IF('[wb]2 Claims'!R8C5 =[Template.xlsx]Claims!R8C5,""Correct"",""Incorrect"")"
```

Edit: Per your add'l code, you have `wb` as a variable. Try this instead

```
"=IF('[" & wb.Name & "]2 Claims'!R8C5 =[Template.xlsx]Claims!R8C5,""Correct"",""Incorrect"")"
```

(Note: you may or may not need the `.Name`)

Comment: Thanks, this is working. However when I run the macro it is asking me to select the wb file from a file explorer. Why is it doing this and not simply calculating the formula?

Comment: @E_McAndrew is that workbook open or closed? Also what is the template.xlsx? You may need to open that or add the full path too.

Comment: At the moment I have both workbooks open, I am hesitant to have the path as the path will change each month depending on the month (although it is probably possible to incorporate this).

Comment: @E_McAndrew - Try `"=IF('[wb]2 Claims'!R8C5 ='[Template.xlsx]Claims'!R8C5,""Correct"",""Incorrect"")"`  ...or maybe just `'[Template]Claims'!...`

Comment: Still doing the same thing, I'm not too sure why as I have another macro which works in the same way, but it doesn't do this.

Comment: I guess the problem is that `wb` is a variable, not the actual name of the workbook.

Comment: @E_McAndrew - Can you post the rest of the relevant code? You may need: `"=IF('[" & wb & "]2 Claims'!R8C5 =[Template.xlsx]Claims!R8C5,""Correct"",""Incorrect"")"`

Comment: I have added the entire script into my question, thanks. I didn't think any other parts were relevant but perhaps they are.